# Add element into javascript "dictionary" array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I got a dict object structure like this:

```
var dict = {
    11: 0,
    12: 0,
    13: 0
    ...
};
```

I want to do this:

```
for (var i = 11; i < 42; i++) {
    dict.Add(i, 0);
}
```

But I do know "Add()" is not a function defined on the dict object.

So, how can I do it insead of manully write 11~42 line by line?

Comment: Exactly the same way you would index an array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
for (var i = 11; i < 42; i++) {
    dict[i] = 0;
}
```

If you want to include `42` per your question, then change the `<` to a `<=`.